# Electronic Configuration and Octave Rule

Tags: orbitals, electronic-configuration

According to Octave rule, a shell cannot hold more than 8 electrons

But according to atomic orbitals,

> The maximum number of electrons in the shell with principal quantum number `n is 2n2`.

How do these rules reconcile?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: They reconcile just fine when $n=2$.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Do they only reconcile when n=2? What about when n≠2?

Comment: When $n\ne2$, things get... complicated.

Comment: The point is, for n>2, the rule 2n^2 is still true, but with delayed filling up of d resp. f orbitals. Therefore n+1 shell starts filling up, when n shell contains just 8 ( s + p ) electrons.

Comment: Octet, not octave.

Comment: @EdV The student or their teacher is mixing octet rule with the law of octaves (part of the early history of the periodic table).

Answer (score 2):

If you look up the time frame of the so called octave law, it is from the mid-19th century (1860s). At that time, electron did not exist, protons did not exist and the concept of atom was not clear.

> According to Octave rule, a shell cannot hold more than 8 electrons

The above statement is blatantly wrong and the textbook teaching this should be trashed. Octave rule was not meant to state this.

Anyway, the formula you quote is correct 2n$^2$.

K is shell no. 1, it can hold 2 electrons

L is shell no. 2, it can hold 8 electrons

M is shell no. 3, it can hold 18 electrons

Answer (score 2):

If exceptions are "forgotten", the teacher can teach to beginners that the octet rule works well "at least" for the $20$ first elements. And these $20$ first elements are the most frequent and most important elements found in elementary textbooks of chemistry. They contain $\ce{C, N, O, F, Na, Mg, Al, Si, P, S, Cl, K}$ and $\ce{Ca}$. These elements and the octet rule are sufficient to develop the basic theory of covalent and ionic bonds for newcomers in the world of chemistry.